# ¿Como funciona frame, position y bounds en el layer de una vista?

Tags: swift

La pregunta sería, como funcionan, que relación tienen entre sí y para que se usa cada uno. Se que hay una documentación de Core Animation pero la verdad que estoy bastante perdido con estas 3 propiedades.

Answer (score 0):

El **Frame** es un rectángulo que tiene la posición y tamaño en función de la *superview*, es decir, sus coordenadas, son relativas a la vista padre.

El **Bound** es un rectángulo que tiene su propio sistema de coordenadas.

Usás **Frame** si querés saber por ejemplo la distancia a la vista padre o posicionarla dentro de la vista padre.

Usás **Bound** si querés agregar alguna *subview* a esta vista o si querés hacer alguna transformación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy hablando de la layer de la vista, no de la vista en si

Comment: El concepto de bound, frame y  position es el mismo en la vista y en el layer de la misma

Comment: @Silvi excelente tu respuesta!.